# Get Firebase notification when app is in background (with only data-payload using REST client)

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to receive notification when the app is in background with the data-payload only. I don't want to send any notification parameters like `"notification" : {"sound": "default"}`

Here is my code to receive the message and build notification.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String URL_KEY = "url";
private static final String TITLE_KEY = "title";
private static final String BODY_KEY = "body";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) { //Here I made the dumb mistake
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

//            Notification Data initialization
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
//            String notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getData().get(TITLE_KEY);
//            String notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String notificationBody = remoteMessage.getData().get(BODY_KEY);
        String receivedUrl = remoteMessage.getData().get(URL_KEY);

//            BuildNotificaiton
        Intent internetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(receivedUrl))
                .setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.suvajit.webview", "com.example.suvajit.webview.MainActivity"))
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        Random generator = new Random();
        PendingIntent btn1Intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, generator.nextInt(), internetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationBody)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Previous", btn1Intent) // #0
                .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Pause", null)  // #1
                .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Next", null)    // #2
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
}
```

This is my manifest:

```
    <service android:name="com.example.suvajit.webview.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.example.suvajit.webview.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

And I'm sending notification using ARC

[image: ARC]

But when I'm sending only data payload notification is **not received even if the app is in foreground**.

```
{ "data": {
    "url": "https://www.google.com",
    "body" : "This is your message",
    "title": "v-comply",
}
"to" : "dOa...hXIWnms"
}
```

When I'm sending `sound` or any thing else as notification parameter and the app is in foreground the notification is working as it should but when its in background its **showing only my project name** , the data part is not received I guess.

```
{ "data": {
    "url": "https://www.google.com",
    "body" : "This is your message",
    "title": "v-comply",
},
"notification" : {
    "sound": "default"
},
"to" : "dOa...hXIWnms"
}
```

Below there are two screenshots of notification when app in background and in foreground respectively.

[image: When App in Background] [image: When app in foreground]

**How can I make it work to get notifications when my app is in background with only data-payload?** Or am I doing something wrong? Someone please give a solution or guide me.

Comment: This type of question is asked many times in stack overflow I guess , but I haven't found the information I wanted. If possible someone please guide me towards a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a very dumb and silly mistake which I have made. I was only sending data payload , but I was checking `remoteMessage.getNotification() != null` which means it doesen't run my code if there is nothing in my notification data. The condition should be like this

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    //Do stuffs to show notification with data payload only
    }
}
```

After all my notification is working as expected.

**This is for other users.**

If someone wants to have both notification and data payload check separately they can include both conditions like this.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        //Do stuffs with data payload only
    }

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        //Do stuffs with notificaiton data
    }
}
```